# how to create a null branch in jgit

Tags: git, jgit

Now I get a temp git non-bare repository. I want to keep a final branch which is empty. What shall I do?

I use clone to get the non-bare repository:

```
git = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(repository.getDirectory().getAbsolutePath()).setDirectory(file)
                .setNoCheckout(true).call();
```

I tryed like this:

```
git.checkout().setName(FINAL_TEMP_BRANCH).setCreateBranch(true).call();
```

But I got the exception:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.RefNotFoundException: Ref HEAD can not be resolved
```

I just want to create a FINAL_TEMP_BRANCH which is empty. What shall I do?

Comment: I find since jgit3.3, it support the method  git.checkout().setOrphan(true).setName("orphanbranch"); to create an new empty branch. What can I do in jgit 3.1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When git clone command called, it will create a "master" branch automatic. But now the head point to nothing. So we should commit something then the head will point to the latest commit. We can do it like this:

```
git = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(repository.getDirectory().getAbsolutePath()).setDirectory(file)
                .setNoCheckout(true).call();
        git.commit().setMessage("Initial commit").call();
        git.branchCreate().setName(FINAL_TEMP_BRANCH).call();
```

Now the git repository has two branch: master and FINAL_TEMP_BRANCH. Both of them are empty.